# Move Cursor Over Selected Control (x,y position)

Tags: c#, wpf, position, location, mouse

As I said in title, I need to move/shake my cursor over selected control ( position of control).

This is how I did it, before anything I get position of control(Button called ***btnMinimize*** is control I am talking about) that I want to position my cursor to. This is how I get **X and Y** position:

```
relativePoint = this.btnMinimize.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

LeftMouseClick(relativePoint.X, relativePoint.Y);
```

Here is definition of LeftMouseClick method:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
       // mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0,0);
       // mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);

}
```

Now, what I want to do after I positioned my cursor over selected control is  to move that mouse 1 pixel left or right, like someone psyhicly touched mouse and moved it, because on this way like I did, I can't see my cursor positioned (even if he is) above selected control until I really move mouse psyhicly..

HERE ARE TWO IMAGES:

first one when I run application:

[image]
I marked with yellow box my btnMinize and as you can see application is runned but cursor is not shown there...

AND HERE IS ANOTHER IMAGE WHEN I TOUCH MY MOUSE PHYSYCALI

[image]

AS YOU CAN SEE ON SECOND IMAGE MOUSE CURSOR IS SHOWN ITS NOT HIDDEN ANYMORE because I touched my mouse which is connected to computer,

so how can I simulate real move or whatever just to show my cursor over my control and move it little bit left or right or whatever, I just want to move it over btnMinimize to make it visible there.

Thanks guys,
CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

after two days struggling I've found solution to this, and because noone posted any of answers I think it is Ok to answer on my own question rather than deleting it because I've found answer.

This is how I solved this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0,0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xpos+5, ypos+5, 0, 0);

        timer.Interval = 1000; // here time in milliseconds
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

 }

 void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
        SetCursorPos(1500, 28);
        timer.Stop();
 }
```

As you can see guys I added few new lines of code:
`mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xpos+5, ypos+5, 0, 0);`// I used this line to move cursor 5 pixels on x and y, just to register some movement, and after that what I did was next,  I used timer to move cursor on certain position on screen after 1 second, and looks like that was the answer I was looking for, because after 1 second cursor is positioned and ***shown*** on new location: `SetCursorPos(1500, 28);` and that is what I was looking for.

Thanks anyway guys,
Cheers